# Was T'Uerell ever mentioned or appeared in any other Star Trek storylines?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-eu

A Vulcan Philosopher named T'Uerell who was obssessed with "logic" and "perfection" was credited as the creator of the Borg in the videogame Star Trek: Legacy. I was wondering if she ever appeared anywhere else as she was very badass.

Comment: [According to this](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/T'Uerell), she has nothing to do with the creation of the Borg.  Rather, she used their technology and took over the Borg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Star Trek : Legacy, T'Uerell isn't credited with having created the Borg. Within [that particular canon](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_history#Legacy), that honour goes to [V'ger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anMOQ3vTy9k).

> A later origin was discovered by the Vulcan scientist T'Uerell during
>   her attempt to become the new controlling entity within the Collective
>   in order to mold the galaxy into a realm of pure logic. After entering
>   a deep meditative state, she mind melded with the Borg Collective
>   consciousness and discovered that the origin of the Collective lies
>   with the human-built machine probe that would be known as "V'Ger."

As regards further appearances of [T'Uerell](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Uerell) in the Star Trek EU, there haven't been any.

They did at least leave the door open for a possible sequel though...